# permission denied when executing a binary

Tags: permissions, files, sudo

I used these [instructions](http://shiftcommathree.com/articles/how-to-install-mongodb-on-os-x) to install mongodb on my OS X machine. I did not make the files owned by root though, I used my local user (markdsievers), and installed to `/usr/local/mongodb` and `usr/local/mongodb_data`. I've chmod'ed and chown'ed all files and subdirectories of those to `rwxrwxr-x  markdsievers  staff`.

As user `markdsievers` I can start up the database without error using:

```
$ sudo mongod --dbpath=/usr/local/mongodb_data
```

However, if I start it with:

```
$ mongod --dbpath=/usr/local/mongodb_data/
```

I get:

```
Unable to create / open lock file for lockfilepath: /usr/local/mongodb_data/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: The directory `/usr/local/mongodb_data` itself must be writable by the user running `mongod`. Is it?

Comment: Hi, it is;          
    `drwxrwxr-x   8 markdsievers  staff  272 11 Jul 06:30 mongodb`

    `drwxrwxrwx   6 markdsievers  staff  204 11 Jul 06:55 mongodb_data`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, an aside: storing your mongo data in `/usr/local/mongodb_data` seems a little strange; most behind-the-scenes storage is in `/var/`, or, for self-installed applications, `/var/local/`. See `hier(7)` or the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html) for more details. (The FHS is mis-named: because it is descriptive, not prescriptive, it is *not* a standard. But it is worth reading.)

Your `mongodb.lock` file is owned by `root` because you executed:

```
sudo mongod --dbpath=/usr/local/mongodb_data
```

`sudo(8)` executes programs with a different *effective user id* (see `seteuid(2)`, `setreuid(2)` for details). Because you didn't specify any other user with a `-u` option, `sudo(8)` defaulted to the `root` account. Thus, your lock file was created with `root` owner and group. (Compare `sudo id` with `id` to see what changes.)

What is strange though, is that the lock file should have been removed when you stop the `mongod` database. Be sure you're stopping it properly -- not only so the lock files are removed -- but also so you know data has been properly saved to disk.

Answer (score 2):

Do an `ls -l /usr/local/mongodb_data/mongod.lock`

I bet that since you ran first as user "root", that file already exists, and owned by root.  Delete it  and I bet it works as user "markdsievers".

Comment: Doh - right you are, the `mongodb.lock` was owned by `root`. One question though - I don't understand your use of "mongodb user". I thought executing a binary it would handle files as the user who spawned it, ie `markdsievers`?

Comment: @BruceEdiger To delete a comment, hover your mouse over it and click on the `×` that appears on the right.